# Is there any way to fully encrypt my hard-drive AFTER an installation of Linux Mint?

Tags: backup, encryption, truecrypt

I'm askin myself, is there any software who can encrypt my whole hard drive with Linux Mint 17.3 on it AFTER the installation? Like TrueCrypt for Windows?!

If not and I've to reinstall everthing is there any possibility to safe all my datas (including the installed programs) to restore it after an successful installation of an fully encrypted OS?

Maybe with this tool (included in Linux Mint): http://www.crmk.de/mintbackuptool.jpg ???

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 it is possible: askubuntu.com/a/1107295/723997

Comment: image not found: mintbackuptool.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the entire hard drive encrypted, even the Linux Mint system partitions, swap, your home, the whole works, then I suspect the easiest would be to:

1. backup your data (the Mint Backup Tool you linked an image to should work, but double-check for files you want backed up that aren't in your home)
2. reinstall with encryption using the installer (I'm *pretty sure* it supports system encryption)
3. then restore your data (home, reinstall programs)

## ***OR***

Just encrypt your home folder now with `ecryptfs-migrate-home` but be sure & read it's [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/ecryptfs-migrate-home.8.html) & should heed it's warnings:

> WARNING:  Make  a  complete  backup  copy  of the non-encrypted data to another system or
>          external media. This script is dangerous and in case of an error, could  result  in  data
>          lost, or lock USER out of the system!
>
> ...
>
> After a successful migration, the USER really must run  ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase(1)  or
>          zescrow(1) and record their randomly generated mount passphrase.

And `ecryptfs-setup-swap` would encrypt your swap too, if interested.

Comment: @cmyk You're welcome :-) Feel free to select (green check-mark) the answer if you think it's the "right" one, and/or Upvote (up arrow to left of answer) if it's useful (if you're able to, may need 15 reputation to upvote, but maybe not required on your own question...)

Comment: Sadly I can't upvote actually. Even not on my own question :((

Comment: @cmyk No problem, if you stay on the site with more Qs & As I'm sure you'll get more "reputation points", I've already upvoted the Q. FYI, http://superuser.com has questions about Linux too, especially good for programs / techniques that are available to other OS's too (open source programs like web browsers, bash, etc) also http://askubuntu.com but they close questions that aren't directly about Ubuntu (even about Ubuntu-derived distros like Mint get closed).  Good luck!

Comment: Why is this even marked as the accepted answer when it doesn't answer the question? The solution to reinstall doesn't answer the question of full-disk encrypting AFTER then install. And this is on top of google when looking for that.

Comment: This answers the "If not and I've to reinstall everthing" part, and IMO is far, far easier than the commented answer (that looks to have 20+ steps involving bind mounts, a removable USB boot partition drive, all to just create a NEW install in a separate partition anyway, which the installer can do 1000x faster and easier IMO)

Answer (score 2):

You can try LUKS to encrypt partition or removable device

You need to install `cryptsetup` utility

```
apt-get install cryptsetup
```

Configure LUKS partition

**The following command will remove all data on the partition that you are encrypting.**

for example to encrpt /dev/xvdc ,type the following command:

```
cryptsetup -y -v luksFormat /dev/xvdc
```

This command initializes the volume, and sets an initial key or passphrase. Please note that the passphrase is not recoverable so **do not forget it**

Type the following command:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/xvdc backup2
```

You can use the following command to see the status:

```
cryptsetup -v status backup2
```

to dump LUKS headers

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/xvdc
```

**Format LUKS partition**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/backup2
```

to save time use `pv`

```
pv -tpreb /dev/zero | dd of=/dev/mapper/backup2 bs=128M
```

create file system:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/backup2
```

To mount the new filesystem :

```
mkdir /backup2
mount /dev/mapper/backup2 /backup2 
df -H
cd /backup2
ls -l
```

to unmount:

```
umount /backup2
```

**To secure DATA**

```
cryptsetup luksClose backup2
```

mount or remount encrypted partition

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/xvdc backup2
mount /dev/mapper/backup2 /backup2
df -H
mount
```

Comment: `pv` "monitor(s) the progress of data through a pipe," it doesn't *save time*, but it would let you guess when the process will be finished